# Manually break tcolorbox in standalone environment

Tags: tcolorbox, standalone

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=4in, multi={my}, crop, ignorerest=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia, forloop}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
  \forloop{loopcntr}{1}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw, skin=enhancedmiddle, breakable, reset box array, store to box array]
  First part\tcbbreak
  Second part\tcbbreak
  Third part
  \end{tcolorbox}

  \boxarraygetsize{\boxsize}

  \expandafter\rpt\expandafter[\the\numexpr \boxsize +1 \relax]{
    \begin{my}%
      \useboxarray{\theloopcntr}%
    \end{my}%
  }

\end{document}
```

It should produce three boxes. But it produces only one box.

How do I get the standalone class to produce three boxes?

Comment: Why don't you simply type three boxes? It looks rather curious to use the rather complicated breakable library and then to force the breaks manually.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. In the real document, the content of the boxes comes from another file. It is easier to insert `\tcbbreak` at an appropriate location in that file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have given more details to the MWE. Now, it is more like the real life sceario.